What is the maximum size of varchar that can be specified in postgresql?
I use varchar(4096) in postgresql.
During data creation, the size of varchar may be exceeded.
So, I want to know max size in psql.
I know that max size is 65,535 characters.
If this is true, I wonder how much of a difference in performance there is when comparing text and varchar.

Error is below.
ERROR: value too long for type character varying(4096)

Amazing enough the docs Character types covers this: If specified, the length n must be greater than zero and cannot exceed 10,485,760. If character varying (or varchar) is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any length.
